# Dependency Injection With Factory Methods

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm fairly new to the the Spring and I'm trying to move our legacy code to spring.I'm trying to auto inject all the dependencies by using @Autowired.

My Bean has a factory method as follows:

```
public static Service getInstance(Registration registration) throws Exception {
    Service service = null;
    switch(registration.getType()) {
        case XServer : 
            service = new XServer(); break;
        case YServer : 
            service = new YServer(); break;
        default : 
            service = new XServer(); break;
    }

    service.setRegistration(registration);
    return service;
}
```

But when I use **new** in the factory method all the dependencies in the new class remains uninitialized. Also if I use **appContext.getBean('beanname')** it throws following exception:

> Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Can some one help me understand how to do it correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, then you are trying to instantiate the factory manually via the **new** command. But the Spring framework must register the beans, when you are trying to use them in the ApplicationContext. You have to create a Factory Bean which provides the creation of common other objects. These objects also have to be registered to the 
Spring config of your application.

[Have a look at the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method)

That means you have to define somewhere in your application beans of following types: XServer, YServer and the type of your Factory Bean. Furthermore you should have a look at [Method Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection), because you are trying to create beans with different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, but found this question helpful: [Inject spring dependency in abstract super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238987/inject-spring-dependency-in-abstract-super-class).
It's not exactly the same, but it handles the point of inheritance. Note that it's using XML instead of annotations.